# Django Forms translate standard error message

Tags: django, forms, translate

All my translations work except the error messages generated by forms.

This is the start of my form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_("First name"), min_length=3, required=True)
```

Now the label "First name" translates fine to "Vorname" because I made a .po file and compiled etc..

However when entering only 2 characters the resulting error is in English and not in (this case) German, see screen print below.

I have looked in [Github Django repository django/conf/locale/de etc.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/conf/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po) but could not find the string "Please lengthen etc." there.

So my question is: how do I get this error message to translate? I assume Django has a standard method and that this string is already in some .po file somewhere within the Django project?

[image]

Comment: This is very likely the browser itself, not Django...

Comment: Ah... right, yes, I see what you mean: in the HTML it says: '''<input type="text" name="first_name" value="ABC" minlength="3" class="form-control is-valid" empty_label="None" required id="id_first_name">'''. So the form puts the min_length check right in the HTML, and then it is obvious the back-end has nothing to do with the error message or translation anymore. Case closed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: yes, likely if you configure the browser in German, and that browser has translations for this, it can show a message in German, but of course that is depending on what the browser does with this. Strictly speaking a browser could just ignore the `minlength=...`, or show messages, or put the text box in red, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `oninvalid` attribute to to that field's widget would work.

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_("First name"), min_length=3, required=True)

  def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
      super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs={
          'oninvalid':"this.setCustomValidity('{German stuff}')",
          'oninput':"this.setCustomValidity('')"
          }
```

#### Edit 1

I've also learned you must add an `oninput` which then clears the message. I'm looking into other ways, because this solution would always show the same message no matter the validation error- is empty or is less 3 chars = same msg

#### Edit 2

This requires some extra javascript, but you should only have to do it once.
There might be more error messages, I only tested it on a Select
references = https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#validating_forms_using_javascript

###### form.py

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_("First name"), min_length=3, required=True)

  def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
      super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs={
          'oninvalid':"germanValidationMsg(this)",
          'oninput':"this.setCustomValidity('')"
          }
```

###### germanvalidation.js

```
function germanValidationMsg(e){
    // dictionary of validations and their status
    console.log(e.validity)

    if (e.validity['badInput']){
        e.setCustomValidity('German badInput Msg');
    } else if (e.validity['patternMismatch']){
        e.setCustomValidity('German patternMismatch Msg');
    } else if (e.validity['rangeOverflow']){
        e.setCustomValidity('German rangeOverflow Msg');
    } else if (e.validity['rangeUnderflow']){
        e.setCustomValidity('German rangeUnderflow Msg');
    } else if (e.validity['stepMismatch']){
        e.setCustomValidity('German stepMismatch Msg');
    } else if (e.validity['tooLong']){
        e.setCustomValidity('German tooLong Msg');
    } else if (e.validity['tooShort']){
        e.setCustomValidity('German tooShort Msg');
    } else if (e.validity['typeMismatch']){
        e.setCustomValidity('German typeMismatch Msg');
    } else if (e.validity['valueMissing']){
        e.setCustomValidity('German valueMissing Msg');
    //} else if (e.validity['customError']){
    //    // customError always seems to be true?
    //    e.setCustomValidity('German customError Msg');
    } else if (e.validity['valid']){
        e.setCustomValidity('');
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. See comment Willem van Onsem. That seems the case here.

Comment: Lol, np. I seemed have have glanced over the question and went on a tangent lmao. my bad